# Why did the ship not return to Zero-G?

Tags: interstellar

Anne Hathaway and Matthew McConaughey travel through space. After leaving the Earth they were in a zero gravity (0g) situation and by spinning up their space craft they acquire the 1g situation again. After reaching the worm hole they stop the space craft from spinning but **surprisingly they seem to remain in the same 1g situation.**

**How?**

Comment: Are movie mistakes and minor plot holes on-topic here?

Comment: @NickT - Hell yes. They represent about 95% of our questions.

Comment: "Anne Hathaway's hair didn't puff out in zero-gravity. How?"

Comment: @NickT - Because she uses hairspray.

Comment: The floating in space look is actually a bi-product of orbitting or "free falling", and not due to the mere fact that you're in space. In the scene describe, the passengers are moving at the same relative velocity as the ship, so there's no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no real evidence of gravity after Romilly asks Cooper to stop the spinning. True, after they stop spinning Romilly is still next to Cooper's chair in the same position he was when he was standing next to the chair in artificial gravity, but we only see him from the chest up, and we don't see him walk around or anything. So, it seems possible that he's still in that position either because he was very careful about not pushing off with his feet, or possibly he had some trick for keeping his position stable like wedging one of his feet under the chair. And after that one scene with Romilly explaining the concept of wormholes as bridges in a higher dimension, the next scene is them actually traveling through the wormhole, it still looks like the ship isn't spinning but they're all strapped into their chairs so the lack of gravity shouldn't matter. Then after exiting the wormhole on the other side, the ship is spinning again in the next shot we see of it.

Answer (score 3):

The film's [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21488063-interstellar) makes it clear that after they stop the craft from spinning, they return to zero-g. Perhaps it's not obvious because of the lack of visual cues and the fact that the crew is strapped in:

> He began firing controlled bursts from the engines, pushing against
>   the direction of rotation. Slowly but inexorably the motion slowed,
>   until the Endurance was motionless—at least relative to its own axis.
>   **And as they ground to a halt, the peculiar belly-tickle of free-fall
>   returned.**